# Failed to execute MI command in debugging native C++ code in Android

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I am trying to debug native `cpp` files in Android and followed the discussion in this [link](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/). I think I go through all the steps and do native code debugging. Debug `Android` application first. Then launch `ndk-gdb-py`. When I launch C++ native debugging, I got error as

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
```

In the Eclipse console, I found that

```
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Function "Java_com_MainActivity_StartCamera" not defined.
```

What could be wrong with this error?
EDIT1:
I could cleared error by keeping 
target remote :5039 in the gdb2.setup file.
Because my eclipse JUNO does not have connection tab.

Then when I do the debugging again, in the console the progress status is `unable to attach to target VM` and Could not `AssignProcesstoObject`. Please see the status report in the console. I am not sure my problem is common or not as I still don't have any discussion yet.

```
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xb00055e1 to 0xb00055e0.
0xafd0c738 in __futex_syscall3 () from C:/libc.so
(gdb) JDB :: java.io.IOException: handshake failed - connection prematurally clo
sed
JDB ::  at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.handshake(SocketTransportSer
vice.java:136)
JDB ::  at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.attach(SocketTransportServic
e.java:232)
JDB ::  at com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericAttachingConnector.attach(GenericAttachingCo
nnector.java:116)
JDB ::  at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketAttachingConnector.attach(SocketAttachingConn
ector.java:90)
JDB ::  at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.attachTarget(VMConnectio
n.java:519)
JDB ::  at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.open(VMConnection.java:3
28)
JDB ::  at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Env.init(Env.java:63)
JDB ::  at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.TTY.main(TTY.java:1066)
JDB ::
JDB :: Fatal error:
JDB :: Unable to attach to target VM.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can make it work for debugging with gdb. The mistake I made is I use command window in debugging. Then I change to cygwin and install cygwin's gcc, then all work fine. Thanks